# How to create Infinite Canvas effect?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, prezi

Infinite Canvas is a page/Form which has Infinite Size or is Very Large. To put it simply, the page doesn't end.

Checkout Prezi or just Google search

I am Trying to create an app which has infinite canvas to draw on/ Write.(Zoom in and Zoom out as well)
One possible way is to use a browser inside a window and use JavaScript to create infinite canvas effect.However, I cannot use browsers as the main control of my app.